# Write a function accumulate_product that accepts one list as a parameter and returns the product of all the numbers in the list that are not zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would prefer if the code is written with a while loop not a for loop. So far this is what I have but it runs on an infinite loop.

```
def accumulate_product(list):
    p = 1
    index = 0
    while index in list:
        p *= index
        if index == 0:
            index += 1
    return p
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up list indices with list items, and for the purpose of aggregating products you don't need indices for the calculation at all.

To implement this with a `while` loop, you can use the `list.pop` method instead so that you can keep popping the list as a stack until it's empty:

```
def accumulate_product(l):
    p = 1
    while l:
        p *= l.pop()
    return p
```